# Cases equation problem - ! Missing { inserted

Tags: errors, equations, cases

I am trying to compile this equation

```
\beta\_t^i=
   \begin{cases}
      \overline{\beta}-i\cdot\sigma\_{\beta} & 0\leq i\leq 4\\
       0.0 & 5\leq i\leq7
  \end{cases}
```

and I am still getting error

```
! Missing { inserted.
```

Old topics didn't help me, I think it will be problem with `\\` or `&` but can't solve it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your code snippet works fine here, when I put it within a complete document. Can you please create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that demonstrates the issue. This works: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\beta\_t^i=\begin{cases}\overline{\beta}-i\cdot\sigma\_{\beta} & 0\leq i\leq 4\\0.0 & 5\leq i\leq7\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}`

Comment: Thanks a lot, i didn't include amsmath, that was the problem.
By the way, can including amsmath cause any visual changes to my previous equations or i shouldn't be worried? I have more than 50 of them in that document already.

Comment: I don't think that you need to worry, probably very small differences, if any. You could always ask a separate question about just that.